# Is "sniff in" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The drug addict sniffed in a line of powder. His eyes then suddenly
>   became red and he became excited and agitated. His eyes became
>   blod-shot red and his breathing shallow and labored.

I am not sure if "sniffed in" is correct.

Comment: It sounds perfectly normal to me. The *in* is not needed, but it's also not required to omit it—and its presence lends emphasis to the description of the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***In*** is not the preposition I would use here. To use no preposition at all is ambiguous, because it might mean he took a sniff at it to smell it, rather than to take it into his body. In British English, the preposition I would expect to be used to make it clear (as if it weren't from context) would be ***up***. To indicate that it wasn't taken into the body, you might use *sniffed **at***, though that's not entirely unambiguous. For your purposes, you might use:

> The drug addict **sniffed up** a line of powder.

However, given that you're talking about drugs, that would not be idiomatic, because there's a specific word used here, idiomatically:

> The drug addict **snorted** a line of powder.

Answer (score 0):

The usual verb that is used is "[snort](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snort)". It is a transitive verb so you don't need "in".